# Getting null location in spite of checking everything

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I wish to access user's position using gps system of phone.

> In manifest I've included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

> I get null location at .appLocationService.getLocation();

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AppLocationService appLocationService;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(MainActivity.this);
}
public void OpenAddress(View v) {
    appLocationService =new AppLocationService(MainActivity.this);
    Location location = appLocationService.getLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        // getting co-ordinates and address
    }
    else showSettingsAlert();
  }
}
```

> I get null location at .getLastKnownLocation(provider);Here i get all locations from all providers. But all seem to return  null location

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
public AppLocationService(){}
Context mcontext;protected LocationManager locationManager;Location location;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60;
public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mcontext=context;
}
public Location getLocation() {
    boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!isGPSEnabled) //enabling it    
    else {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
            Location bestLocation = null;
            for (String provider : providers) {
                Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (l == null) continue;
                if(bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy())
                    bestLocation=l;
            }
            return bestLocation;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution. I have wrote it and works pretty good on my device. I have shared on github as well.

Github: [click here](https://github.com/shahzadafridi/GpsLocation)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppLocationService mAppLocationService;
    boolean mBounded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callLocation);

    }

    public void OpenAddress(View view){
        Location location = mAppLocationService.getLastKnownLocation();
        if (location != null){
            Log.e("location","latitude:"+location.getLatitude()+" longtitude"+location.getLongitude());
        }else {
            Log.e("location","location return null");
        }
    }

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

            mBounded = true;
            AppLocationService.LocalBinder binder = (AppLocationService.LocalBinder) service;
            mAppLocationService = binder.getInstance();

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBounded = false;
            mAppLocationService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AppLocationService.class);
        bindService(i,mConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBounded){
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBounded = false;
        }
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="OpenAddress"
        android:text="Location"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AppLocationService.java**

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    Location location;
    Context mcontext;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60;
    IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        public AppLocationService getInstance(){
            return AppLocationService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60;
        Location bestLocation = null;
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (Permissions.getInstance(this).checkLocationPermission()) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
                for (String provider : providers) {

                    Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                    if (l == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                        bestLocation = l;

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("check", "Gps is not enable");
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shahz.testing">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<service android:name=".AppLocationService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Start service before calling the getLocation method.

Comment: The approach you have implemented in your code is wrong, you can't get direct data from service you to use broadcast receiver which can send data from service to activity

Comment: @DhritiDhruve hey check the answer now.

Comment: Thank you @Opriday. I shall implement it later and let you know if any other problem still persists